# jquery - How to make scroll in window area and iframe scrll too at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

jquery - How to make scroll in window area and iframe scrll too at the same time?

below is my code but can't work

```
$(window).scrollTop() = $('body iframe').scrollTop();
```

ex: http://i.imgur.com/1gfhi.png

```
<html><head><title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).scrollTop() = $("body iframe").scrollTop();
 $(window).scrollLeft() = $("body iframe").Left();
</script>
<style type="text/css">
 .header{
    position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 0px;
background-color: black;
width: 1000px;
height: 100px;
 }
 .iframecontent{
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top:100px;
 }
 .footer{
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
top: 500px;
background-color: green;
width: 1000px;
height: 100px; 
 }  
</style>
</head><body>
<div class="header"></div>
<iframe class="iframecontent" src="iframecontent.html" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<div class="footer"></div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).scrollTop() = $("body iframe").scrollTop();
 $(window).scrollLeft() = $("body iframe").Left();
 </script>

 use this script in iframecontent.html.
```

Comment: this will working but we need to remove iframe after body tag

Comment: This won't ever work because you can't assign something to the return value of a function.

Comment: @pimvdb sorry i am not see that console log we remove "= $("body").scrollTop()" and "= $("body").Left()" work right?

Comment: First, `window` is still specific to the iframe, not the main page. Removing what you say doesn't work either, because it doesn't do anything in that case.